# Estimating quantity of equally sized objects in a circle with variables.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[Example of 3m Round Discs Arrayed in 360 on a circle 19.2m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My596.png)
3Meter  Discs are Polar Arrayed in a circle 360 degrees. I need to be able to accurately estimate the maximum amount of objects i can polar array 360 degrees with minimum allowed distance between them 0.19 M and maximum 0.31 M.

For instance my circle diameter is 19.4169 meters the object is a round Disk 3 meters in diameter the maximum amount of objects that would fit this circle is 19.  The minimum allowed distance between objects is 0.18 meters and maximum is 0.31 meters.
   Is there a formula that I can apply to get an accurate calculation to polar array objects sized 3 Meters that I can apply to circles with varying diameter for instance circle with a diameter of 20m, 22m, 26m and so on.

Comment: If there are 19 objects, the space allotted to each of them is $61/19=3.21$ m, and the distance between the objects is $3.21-3=0.21$ m. What more do you need?

Comment: I am not sure I really understand your question. Personally I would need some more information. When you say circumference do you mean a circle? When you say the circumference is 61 meters, do you mean its length is 61 meters, i.e. its perimeter? What is the shape of your object? is it a circle bounding a disk or something more complicated?  Then what is your goal? Do you want your objects to be packed as densely as possible? Do you just need an upper bound on the number of objects you can fit?

Comment: What do you mean the objects are arrayed? Is there a predefined structure of the way the objects should be placed?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The object is a circle with a diameter of 19.4169 meters  = 61 meter circumference.  The objects are Polar Arrayed 360 degrees.  I need to be able to accurately estimate the maximum amount of objects i can polar array 360 degrees with minimum allowed distance between them 0.19 M and maximum 0.31 M.  This is why I am wondering if there is a formula that can be applied to make this calculation.   Thank you for your help once again.

Answer (score 1):

[Packomnia](http://www.packomania.com/) has figures for packing circles in circles. For your case $\frac 3{19.4169} \approx 0.1545$ so you can pack $32$ circles.

[image]Packing problems are *hard*.  This page gives the best known packings, but most of them are not proven to be optimal.  For other diameters of the outer circle, you can find the ratio of the small circle to the outer circle and look in the table to find how many you can pack, then look in the figures to find the arrangement.

Added:I didn't understand Polar Arrayed.  An approximation, accurate when there are many circles, is to compute the circumference of your circle, here $19.4169\pi$.  Take each circle to use $3$ m of that and compute how much is left.  The error comes from the fact that the arc of the $19.4169$ circle is not a diameter of the $3$ circle, but that is quite small. This gives $\frac {19.4169 \pi -19 \cdot 3}{19}\approx 0.21$ spacing between your circles.  More accurate is to asses the angle subtended by the outer circle. If $r$ is the radius of the small circle and $R$ is the radius of the circle on which the centers lie, the angle subtended is $\2 \arcsin \frac rR$.  See the figure below.
[image]  For small angles, $\arcsin x \approx x$.  You can see how much of the $2 \pi $ radians is occupied with your circles, then the rest goes into your spacing.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Great place to learn packing circles.  However my question was about arraying circles 360deg on a gived diameter.  I made a visual example of what I'm talking about. here is an example image.http://i.stack.imgur.com/My596.png